# How are global classes and/or components treated in 2nd Generation Packaging (unlocked and managed)

Tags: apex, lightning-components, second-generation-packaging, global

In 1st generation packaging, a global class cannot be modified after a managed release (and installation). There have been numerous discussions like [this one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160114/modifying-a-global-class-in-a-managed-package-with-deprecated) on handling / upgrading / deprecating global classes and components in 1st generation packages.

How are global classes and components treated in 2nd Generation Packaging considering unlocked and managed package versions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Unlocked Packages**

For Unlocked packages, you can revert a class from global to public or even to private and it should allow you to do it fine because it simply does not matter.

**2GP Managed Packages**

You can downgrade an Access modifier of a class from `global` to `public` or even `private` provided you create a new package version from the source **with no ancestry**. That is in short you cannot downgrade **without breaking package ancestry**.

To learn more about ancestry take a look [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_config_ancestors.htm)

In short, what specifying `ancestry` during the package version creation process does is, maintains upgradability rules for you (Like Rules that are needed to ensure release does not suddenly break something in consumer org).

**Effect of creating a Managed Package with No Ancestry**

> If an org already has the package version installed with the global class you cannot upgrade the org with the new package version (where apex class is public/private) with different ancestry without uninstalling the previous versions. Note this will mean you will have to restore the data along. You want to avoid this.

So in short if you have a Released Managed 2GP package that already has a global class and is installed in a number of orgs if you try going back to public/private, it simply won't be allowed during the packaging process without you taking off the `ancestorId` during package creation.

Now if you take off the `ancestorId` it simply means you have branched off at that point and would mean destructive change for the customer who already has the app installed.

> Using `Global` classes should be avoided in 2GP if one can since the public class can be made available to other packages within the same [namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_NamespaceAccessible.htm).

Note be above applies to all the components. This is called manageability rules and documented in 1GP package upgrade components behaviour in ISV document and they are all applied. These are documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm#component_properties)

Comment: +1 - I believe breaking ancestry also means you lose Security Review approval, if applicable.

Comment: That's exactly what I suspected when I saw the Q over on twitter. Totally makes sense.

Comment: The security review aspect is an important aspect, thanks @DavidReed

Comment: Can I assume these rules apply for other metadata components that can be global (aura) or behave similarly (e.g. protected labels, custom metadata)? Would love to see them added to the answer

Comment: Yes this apply for everything. This is called manageability rules and they are all applied.